# Dart: Exit a function from if within a foreach loop

Tags: loops, flutter, dart, foreach, break

I want to break the function after the `if` statement, but I unable to do so.

Below is my code snippet.

> ```
> void addOrderToCart(Product product, int quantity, String color, String size) {
>     _lastOrder = Order(product, quantity, _orderId++, color, size);
>
>     _orders.forEach((element) {
>       if(element.product.id == _lastOrder.product.id){
>        element.colors.add(color);
>        element.sizes.add(size);
>        element.quantity = element.quantity + quantity;
>        notifyListeners();
>        return;
>       }
>     });
>     _orders.add(_lastOrder);
>     notifyListeners();
>   }
> ```

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you should return `bool` or any other instead of `void` and use `for` instead of `forEach`.

Here's the solution you looking for.

> ```
> bool addOrderToCart(Product product, int quantity, String color, String size) {
>     _lastOrder = Order(product, quantity, _orderId++, color, size);
>
>
>     for(var element in _orders){
>       if (element.product.id == _lastOrder.product.id) {
>         element.colors.add(color);
>         element.sizes.add(size);
>         element.quantity = element.quantity + quantity;
>         notifyListeners();
>         return true;
>       }
>     }
>     _orders.add(_lastOrder);
>     notifyListeners();
>     return true;
>   }
> ```

Hope this helps.

Good day.

Answer (score 6):

> Dart does not support non-local returns, so returning from a callback
> won't break the loop. Dart forEach callback returns void.

You can use `any` instead of `forEach` since `any` callback returns bool. So you can modify your code as follows.

```
void addOrderToCart(Product product, int quantity, String color, String size) {
    _lastOrder = Order(product, quantity, _orderId++, color, size);

    final alreadyInCart = _orders.any((element) {
      if (element.product.id == _lastOrder.product.id) {
       element.colors.add(color);
       element.sizes.add(size);
       element.quantity = element.quantity + quantity;
       notifyListeners();
       return true;
      }
      return false;
    });

    if (alreadyInCart) {
        return;
    }    

    _orders.add(_lastOrder);
    notifyListeners();

  }
```

Hope this will help you.

Happy coding!